# How can I import thousands documents that are 'files'

Tags: r, file, import

I need to import a file folder with thousands of files. They are not csv, xlsx, txt files, they just say file under type(data type). I have tried multiple ways to import them as well as running R as an administrator.

I have tried different permutations of this code using different read.csv,delim etc but I am unable to import the files.

```
baseball <- read.csv('C:/Users/nfisc/Desktop/Spring 2021/CIS 576/Homework/Homework 5/rec.sport.baseball', stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A file must have an extension in order to correctly identify what the file type is. So in your case, what is the extension of the files?

Comment: That's the issue. I did try csv etc, but that is not the file type. When I click properties on the file, the file type just says file. It opens with Notebook++

Comment: On properties, look at Type of file and it will have an extension in parenthesis. ALL FILES  contain an extension. So you first must tell us what the file type is. If you do not know the file type then we cant help. for example, R cannot open executable files, batch files etc

Comment: I apologize, but I tried that and I can not see anything besides the word file. I tried to import the folder using file_raw, and it did not error, but no data was imported. I am unable to include a picture of the file because I am a new user to stackoverflow.

Comment: You cannot import if you do not know the type of file. Try to learn what the type of file is. Since you said you can open it using Notepad++, it is a human readable file and therefore it does indeed have an extension. Once you figure out what the extension is, you can then ask your question. Otherwise it is fruitless. Probably you could just use `readLines(your file)`. Also try using `list.files()` function to determine the extension if you do not know how to find the extension

Comment: That helped. After I did list.files it told me that it was a desktop.ini file

Comment: Then that means that you can only use `readLines` to read the file into R.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific about what these files are? Does it open into Excel? What kind of data does it represent?

Without an extension, it may be difficult to import.

If you right-click the files and go to "properties", what does it say under "Type of File"?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is late, but I figured out how to input text data. The original issue also was that the file was a rar file and not a zip file.

## Import text data # Make V Corpus from a specified directory

baseball_messages <- tm::VCorpus(tm::DirSource("C:/Users/nfisc/Desktop/Spring 2021/CIS 576/Homework/Homework 5/usebaseball"))

hockey_messages <- tm::VCorpus(tm::DirSource("C:/Users/nfisc/Desktop/Spring 2021/CIS 576/Homework/Homework 5/usehockey"))